# How to get the complete query that is currently running

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to get (for debug reasons) the currently running query with the query below :

```
SELECT sqltext.TEXT,
req.session_id,
req.status,
req.command,
req.cpu_time,
req.total_elapsed_time
FROM sys.dm_exec_requests req
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(sql_handle) AS sqltext
```

With this query, I get the currently running query's but not the complete query because it's cut off when the query is too big.

Is there a way to get the complete query instead of the cut-off version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the options **Results To Text** (or **Results To File**) in the management studio by pressing **CTRL + T** in the query window.

[image]

There is an option to set the maximum number of characters options in  tools | Options dialog on the Query Results | SQL Server | Results to Grid page.

[image]

Same for results to grid, there it is maximum number of character per row.

[image]